# Как из 2 csv файлов с общим id сделать одну таблицу с данными на Python?

Tags: python, sql, база-данных, sqlite, csv

Есть 2 файла client.csv(15гб 160 млн строк) и phone.csv

Пример файла client.csv:

| id | name | email | contract_number | address_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Пупкин Вася | Pupkin_Vasya@mail.ru | 43784578 | 5283512 |

Пример файла phone.csv:

| id | phone |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 79999999999 |

В итоге надо получить:

| id | phone | name | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 79999999999 | Пупкин Вася | Pupkin_Vasya@mail.ru |

Записать надо только нужные данные, либо в csv либо в таблицу SQLite

В теории надо: читать ту которую с номерами и по id смотреть данные из другого файла, но как это сделать не совсем понятно

Comment: В теории надо свою попытку решения приложить однако.

Comment: Создаём финальную таблицу со всеми полями из первого файла. Грузим первый файл в финальную таблицу. Создаём временную таблицу со всеми полями из второго файла. Грузим второй файл во временную таблицу. Добавляем поле в финальную таблицу.  Апдейтим финальную таблицу. Дропаем временную таблицу. Всё.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать с помощью библиотеки pandas (не забудьте `import pandas as pd`):

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[123], 'name': ['Вася Пупкин'], 'email': ['Pupkin_Vasya@mail.ru'], 'usless_info': [1]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[123], 'phone': [79999999999], 'usless_info': [1]})
df = pd.merge(left=df_2[['id', 'phone']], right=df_1[['id', 'name', 'email']], how='left', on='id')
df.to_csv('final.csv', index=False)
```

В результате обЪединенный .csv будет сохранен как `final.csv`.

Comment: файл client.csv 160 млн строк, на pandas долго будет я думаю

Comment: @Caxa pandas использует C(a не Python) внутри, так что скорость нормальная, библиотека специально сделана для этого, в принципе в ней можно работать и с таблицами SQL, но я за это не шарю, только за csv

Comment: @Caxa просто попробуйте) Если не сложно, напишите потом, за сколько примерно выполнилось обЪединение)

Comment: Хорошо, принцип понятен, но у вас указано решение 1 строки, а как сделать автоматизацию полностью всего файла, немного не понятно

Comment: @Caxa это будет работать для таблиц любой длинны. Просто для примера использовал однострочные. Суть та же, просто используйте 3 строку кода, только вместо df_1 и df_2 используйте имена таблиц, которые сделаны из тех csv файлов, которые надо объединить
Это делается так: имя_1_таблицы = pd.read_csv('путь до файла csv')

Comment: прощу прощения не сразу понял значение строчек df_1/2 = pd.DataFrame
Сейчас попробую

Comment: @Caxa ничего страшного, бывает, напишите потом, получилось ли все)

Comment: Не большая поправка, пример файла не полный, там есть ещё куча ненужных мне данных. В примере указано только то что мне надо забрать.

Comment: @Caxa ща исправлю ответ, там изи, надо указать нужные столбцы только

Comment: @Caxa исправил, в merge просто указываем те столбцы, которые попадут в финальную таблицу

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: Возникли ещё некоторые вопросы не могли бы вы дать для связи свой телеграм например?

Comment: Файл client.csv весит 15гб, на моем пк 16гб оперативной памяти а пандас загружает всё в оперативку

Comment: @Caxa тг '@step1709' (без кавычек не пускает)

Comment: @Caxa можно попробовать производить вычисления в гугл колаб, там вроде 30гб оперативки